# Laravel Eloquent - Set column inside Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a "tickets" table for create bug-report system. This ticket has an `enum` `status` column that is either `open`, `close`, or `solved`.

Instead of opening/closing/solving the ticket inside the controller, I just want to do it within the model; i.e. I want to have functions called `open()`, `close()`, and `solved()` so that I can just go `Ticket::find($id)->close();`. This should set the attribute `status` to `close` and then SAVE it!

What's the best approach for this? Also, would this be considered bad practice? Should I do this within the controller?

I tried doing this, but did not succeeded:

```
public function close()
{
   $this->status = 'close';
   // Also tried $this->attributes['status'] = 'close';
   $this->save();
}
```

Comment: Your sample code should work fine. Do you get an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a perfect thing to put in a model, IMO.

```
class Ticket extends Eloquent {
  public function open() {
    $this->status = 'open';
    $this->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work for some reason. There are no error, nothing. The database is not updated

Comment: @Kousha Are you sure your enum values are what you're using (i.e. closed vs. close)? There's no reason this shouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The value is set (if I echo `$this->status` after I've set it). Its the same that doesn't actually save it. There are no errors. I even tried this on an `integer` type column, but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this is the better way than doing it directly from `controller` and you may use [scopeMethod](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes) for this, for example:

```
function scopeClose($query)
{
    // Close the ticket and return $query;
    return $query->where('...');
}
```

If you return the `$query` then you may do method chaining. For example:

```
Ticket::find($id)->close()->otherMethodCall();
```

If you execute the `query` for example, `$query->update('...')` then returning the `$query` won't make any sense because it'll be the result of `update` method and which is `true/false`.

The benefit to use the `scope` method is:

```
// In your model
function scopeClose($query, $id)
{
    $model = $query->find($id);
    $model->status = 'whatever';
    $model->save();
    return true; // Or just return $model->save();
}
```

So you may use in your `controller`:

```
Ticket::close(10); // Update the status of record with id 10
```

Comment: `close()` is an action. It's supposed to alter the result set, not filter it. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @Mark, was just going to say that. Shouldn't I use the `attribute` or something?

Comment: It's not suppose to do filter, well it may not but it's an example to clarify about it's use.

Comment: @Mark, yes and I've used it before.

Comment: Yes, but my question is the code for your comment. I know how to use the filtering. I want to know how to set the attribute within the model and then save it!

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `update()` function, but before doing that, you've got to make sure that the columns to update are indeed inside the `$fillable` array.

```
//make sure in fillable
protected $fillable = [
   'status',
];

// ...

// In your model
public function close()
{
    $this->update([
       $this->status = 'close'; 
    ]);
}
```

Cheers.